# How to check if user have exists specific letter on table

Tags: php, html

I am trying to check if a user has a specific letter on SQL table like:

I have SQL Table amx_amxadmins and columns id, username, access example:

```
amx_amxadmins:
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | USERNAME         | ACCESS                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | TEST1            | abcde                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | TEST2            | bcde                   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

The Flag A is for `No Access`.

So how do I check if user have in column access A or not?

For example:

````
<?php
    $check_user_flag = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `$amxadmins` WHERE `username` = '$logged[username]' AND `access` LIKE 'a' ") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $checkUSRFLAG = $check_user_flag->fetch_assoc();
    if($checkUSRFLAG->num_rows >  "a"){
        echo "test";
    }
    else {
        echo "test2";
    }
?>
```
````

EDIT BY RyffLe

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$amxadmins` WHERE `username` = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
    $param = $logged['username'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->bind_result();
    $stmt->close();

    $Permissions = $obj->access;

    if (strpos($Permissions, 'a')) {
       echo("An A has been found!");
    }
    else {
       echo("An A wasn't Found...");
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: please explain better your problem, and write some code you tried to solve it

Comment: here `if($checkUSRFLAG->num_rows >  "a")` change it to `if($checkUSRFLAG->num_rows >  0)` ,also add `%` i.e :  `access LIKE 'a%'` to your query.

Answer (score 1):

First of all wellcome on Stackoverflow Beytula Ibryam.

Thats Your table:

```
amx_amxadmins:
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | USERNAME         | ACCESS                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | TEST1            | abcde                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | TEST2            | bcde                   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

First of all you need to select all Data of the User you need to check from your Data:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$amxadmins` WHERE `username` = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$param = $logged[username];
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
$obj = $result->fetch_object();
```

Next is to get your access as string:

```
$Permissions = $obj->access;
```

Now we can go to check the access for your wanted literals:

```
if (strpos($Permissions, 'a')) {
   echo("An A has been found!");
}
else {
   echo("An A wasn't Found...");
}
```

Enjoy ;)

--- EDITS ---

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `?` WHERE `username` = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $amxadmins, $logged['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    $obj = $result->fetch_object();

    if($checkUSRFLAG->num_rows >  "a"){
        echo ("test");
    }
    else {
        echo("test2");
    }
```

If you don't have a MySQLi Connection File, add following lines in to your main file:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('YOUR_DATABEAS_IP', 'YOUR_DATABEAS_USER', 'YOUR_DATABEAS_USER_PASSWORD', 'YOUR_DATABEAS_NAME', 'YOUR_DATABEAS_PORT');
        if($mysqli->connect_error) {
          exit('Error connecting to database'); //Should be a message a typical user could understand in production
        }
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thank you RuffLe, same thing sorry about my explain :/  but when i put this code my page isn`t work and not getting any error only can`t include page,  page show empty     

any idea :/

Comment: can you use line breaks and indents in your code so we can read it better. Next point is, do you use an framework or do you write everything by your self?

Comment: just using some config base for the getting new mysqli and yes i write everything by myself  sometimes getting  helps by examples and like this

Comment: and sorry i not understand your realy about `can you use line breaks and indents in your code`

Comment: please take a look in my "EDITS" Section. I wrote your whole code completely new. try it out ;) and don't forget the `<?php` and `?>` tag ;)

Comment: still same empty maybe cant run ` $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $amxadmins, $logged['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    $obj = $result->fetch_object();
` Here i thing and on your "EDITS" $checkUSRFLAG->num_rows > 0 how you calling $checkUSRFLAG->num_row when you dont have function for it

Comment: What version does your PHP run on?

Comment: Another question, is your MySQLi connection made in the file?

Comment: First i want to say thank you for your helping :) and yes i include config file on my index page and after then i show my pages like include - no problem with mysqli connection file and my php version  5.5 i run your first code like this i show you on my post EDITS - all done but if its  letter a , showed all time `An flag a wasn't found`  if i delete it same ...

Comment: and if i put `$obj = $result->fetch_object();` code not working .. :/

Comment: You are using a old version of PHP you should update it for security reasons. The newes Version is 7.3, 7.4(UnStable) and 8(UpComing) you should update your server to 7.3 to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for a wildcard search.  Use the `%` character for that.  So instead of this:

```
AND `access` LIKE 'a'
```

You'd have this:

```
AND `access` LIKE '%a%'
```